# Do I need a single instance of the Unity container?

Tags: c#, silverlight, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Sorry for this noob question.  I'm beginning to use the Unity 2.0 container with Silverlight and am putting some singletons in it.  For the singletons to work, do I need to have just one instance of the container in my application?  I assume that making a new unity container instance whenever I want to look up my singletons will result in separate containers with separate singletons.

Thanks,
-Jon

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a single instance of a container to achieve singleton behaviour.
Also you need to register your singleton classes with ContainerControlledLifetimeManager.

Comment: +1 Correct, although you don't need a Singleton instance of the container - you just need a single instance of the container (see my answer for an elaboration).

Answer (score 9):

It's a little confusing, because when we refer to **Singletons in DI terminology**, we don't mean the same as the [Singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Basically, the **Singleton Lifestyle** behaves as a (pattern) Singleton **within the same container**, but if you create and use it from a new instance of the container, you will get a different instance.

You can say that the **Singleton Lifetime** is a **locally scoped** Singleton.

To summarize on container usage, you don't need a Singleton container, but you need a **single container instance** to use the Singleton Lifestyle.

To make matters more confusing, in Unity the Singleton lifestyle is called `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`...

Comment: You are messing up patterns and implementation techniques.

Comment: @George Polevoy: No, I'm not - I'm trying to explain the differences. Singleton is a design pattern, but Singleton Lifestyle is also a pattern. It's a DI Container lifestyle pattern that we see in all containers, although it has differing names. Other container lifestyle patterns include Transient, Per Resolve, Per HTTP Request, Per Thread, etc.

Comment: You're answer is a bit confusing. Try adding examples to illustrate what you are saying.